# Hide my source code vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I had tried to lock with Confuser but antivirus says it is virus in there.

How can I hide or lock my source code to prevent users looking my source code with net reflactor or similarities?

Comment: I use Confuser. Out of curiosity, which antivirus do you use and which virus does it say it detects? My AV (McAfee) doesn't detect anything, but running it thru VirusTotal's online scan gets one single false positive detection...which I've just chosen to ignore and use Confuser anyway.

Comment: Can you give me your config file?

Comment: I'm using: anti ildasm, constants, ctrl flow, anti dump, anti debug, invalid metadata. Also: No packer. Random seed.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me too.

Comment: I have been using eazfuscator.net for years; it is a great tool, very easy to use, and support has been top notch